# Rails Route missing in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an a Rails 3.2 App that show an error for Route not found in production 
but not in development. I ran rake Route on my local machine and on the server and the text below show they are identical. I checked the route config file and it was identical and the views were the same. THe exact message I get in production is:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

The two outputs from rakes routes is:

Rake Route Development:

```
harvest GET    /harvest(.:format)                                     visits#harvest
```

Rake Route from Production

```
harvest GET    /harvest(.:format)                                     visits#harvest
```

I am stumped is there anything else to look at. THe local machine is a Macbook the server is Centos

Comment: and logs in production shows nothing more?

Comment: restarted your production server after deploy?

Comment: Super late to the party, but...I ran into this because I had forgotten to run migrations on my production server.  `rake db:migrate` cleared it up.